# Custom Option Price is not changing

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options, simple-product, drop-downs

Hi I've been working with this website but I'm not a Magento Pro.

In this link http://www.joliefi.com/cabinet this item is simple product just using Custom option. When you choose a size it should change the color. Before it was working fine and didn't find any problem just so recent that it's not. The price always changed to 0, but when you add it to cart and/or checkout the prices are correct. It's just on the product page.

In this link also, http://www.joliefi.com/test-fashion/test-men/t722-brown , it is changing the price accordingly, but this item is configurable product. So I was wondering what went wrong and why so sudden. I hope someone here can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.9.2.4: Custom Options price not changing](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140720/magento-1-9-2-4-custom-options-price-not-changing)

Answer (score 1):

go to app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/layout/catalog.xml

in below action

```
<catalog_product_view>
</catalog_product_view>
```

add this code

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

</reference>
```